# WPF Datagrid Dynamic Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

This is a little complicated I think, I'll do my best to explain.

I have the following tables;

**Timesheets**
idTimesheet
id_User
EndDate
Submitted
Approved

**LineItems**
idLineItem
id_Timesheet
Description

**Days**
idDay
id_LineItem
Date
Hours

So, as you can see, this is a Timesheeting system.
I've gotten myself to the point where I can display each line item individually, the problem is figuring out how to display the hours for each day in the relevant column.

I'm using `Timesheets.EndDate` to dynamically generate the `Day` columns in the GridView so that they can have the date in each column too, but I'm at a loss as to how to bind the days/hours to the relevant column. They are DataGridTextColumns as the end goal is to allow the user to enter thier own hours into the system. I'm using EntityFramework, so the Days can be aquired using `LineItem.Ref_Days` which provides an `ICollection<Days>` although, that can easily to be converted to a List or other useful object with the help of LINQ.

Happy to provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to display the hours for each day in the relevant column.

Don't try to use a straight entity and bind to properties which don't expose what is needed. Either create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) object with the business logic (and all models which make up the logic) needed expressed as properties which draw from the original properties, or extend the entity from EF via a partial class definition. Put in the smarts to update the actual properties in the setters of the new properties created.

Either way you simply bind the columns to the new properties either on the actual *extended* entity or the DTO.

Comment: I suspected that might be the best option not long after posting this question and started working on something while waiting for an answer. Much appreciated for the confirmation.